# Why does Jenkins' Stage View not show my jobs as ending?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins' remote API (XML & JSON) to submit Jobs, run them & retrieve the logs. When observing the jobs in Stage View, I noticed that (following a change in my "submission function") the jobs are shown as "processing" while they have completed:
[image]

How can one deal with such issues? (I'm not a DevOps person, I am developer that happened to be chosen as the one to deal with Jenkins. I had no courses or so, just received a sample script and googled the rest)

Ah, I mentioned that change in my submission function: not knowing anything, when my submitted jobs were rejected (because a job with that name already existed), I created unique names for my jobs. This created lots of workspaces that IT wasn't happy with, so I learned how I could update existing jobs and changed my code accordingly. That's when I started seeing neverending jobs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins stage view is in fact showing that the jobs have ended.  More specifically, the jobs have failed, as indicated by the "failed" in the bottom-right corner of the stage which failed.

Comment: Yes, but notice the progress bar under the header 13min28s - this seems to indicate that something is still being worked on. (Or maybe I misinterpret, but usually a completed job does not show such indicators)

Comment: @MBaas that's not a progress bar.  It's showing what chunk of the total execution time that stage consumes.  Compare it to the bars for the next two stages to the right, which show that those stages consumed smaller chunks of time towards the end of the pipeline execution.

Comment: @jayhendren, perhaps add the progress elaboration to your answer zto make it complete.

Comment: Thanks! I misinterpreted that :(